# Return table with json

Tags: sql, postgresql, set-returning-functions

I have the stored procedure **sp_table** in PostgreSQL. I wish to obtain the following result

`(1,{"cola":1,"colb":"a"}) (2,{"cola":2,"colb":"b"})`

With the second column in json format so that my backend can convert it into. but the sp gives me the json with double quotes.

I can only get it the way I want it when I return a column as a json as in the sp **sp_only_json**.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/c82c1b/1

It's possible to obtain it in the desired format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the function returns a table, it should be used in the `FROM` clause to get separate columns as the result.

```sql
SELECT * FROM sp_table();
```

[SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/c82c1b/5)